# facebook ad_status and adgroup_status

Tags: facebook-graph-api, adgroup

In facebook adgroup API only adgroup_status is introduced as a filed. however, when you issue a query to fetch an adgroup fields, ad_status is also retrieved. what is the difference between these two? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

From Facebook PMD group (February 2, 2012):

Question:

> Sylvain Eche Hello we found a parameter ad_status in adgroup that is
>   undocumented
>
> "ad_status": 2, "adgroup_status": 8,
>
> we suspect ad_status = 2 means the campaign is finished Can you update
>   the doc with ad_status
>
> tnx

Answer:

> This is a deprecated parameter which should be
>   ignored. We will remove it from the API soon."
>   http://www.facebook.com/groups/pmdprogram/permalink/292366244154051/